# How can i deny an unit from deactivating Code Insigth in Firemonkey?

Tags: delphi, autocomplete, firemonkey

I want to import an unit to save ini files with this unit from [Github](https://github.com/freeonterminate/delphi/blob/master/FMX.IniFile/FMX.IniFile.pas), but, as soon as i import it, code insight stops working - instead of opening itself doesn't even open anymore. It isn't a change in the IDE options, as it works in every unit/project in which i don't use it. So, the line

```
Uses:  [...], FMX.IniFile;
```

Seems to deactivate Code Insight. I use Rad Studio 10.3. Is this a known issue or does a solution already exists?

Thanks

Edit: In order to use the file correctly, i need to import the files for android and Apple as well, which are in the same directory as the main FMX.IniFile.Pas, these might cause the problem as well

Comment: Which part of CodeInsight are you referring to? The part, that is supposed to mark erroneous parts of code? It is widely considered to be defect and should be disabled immediately after install, to save some CPU time. In any case, you should update to 10.3.1

Comment: No, the part where it shows possible things while editing, like the if you type Button1. Then it will show up like button1.enabled and stuff like that. I guess it's called code completion @sherlock70

Comment: Units added don't have anything to do with disabling Code Completion or Code Insight. The only time I've ever seen completion stop working when adding a unit is when either the IDE can't find it or when the unit has errors that prevent compiling.

Comment: @ken white Please try it with the unit i linked, as soon as i bind it in the code completion stops working - while the program works and compiles without any errors or warnings. I don't see the issue either, so thats why i need help with it. I don't know how these things are connected, but obviously something in the units prevent the code completion from working

Comment: Describe how you are importing the unit.  Into a package or what?

Comment: No, i just copied the files from github(which work great, i haven't found a better way to save variables yet) and copy them into the project folder. Then i just added them as discribet in the uses, and as soon as i did that it always "deactiavtes" the code completion @martynA

Comment: Wait are you adding both `FMX.IniFile.Apple` and `FMX.IniFile.Android` to uses section in your project? You don't need that. Those files are already included in `FMX.IniFile.pas ` file.

Comment: The one and only unit you should be adding to your uses clause is `FMX.IniFile.pas`. If you're doing something other than that, you've created the issue yourself. :-)

Comment: Oops, my mistake, that sounded not like it should. I don't add them to the uses clause, but i add them into the directory of the project in order to make FMX.IniFile to be able to use them.

Comment: @MaxH. That is not how it works, and not how you are supposed to do that. Please consult either the online help on using units http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Programs_and_Units_(Delphi)#Unit_References_and_the_Uses_Clause or more specifically check out http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Multi-Device_Applications_Index. There is very rarely the need to copy any of the installed files anywhere.

Comment: @Sherlock70 Well, i did it exactly like described in the article, but it doesn't seem to solve the problem - it found the file before that as well

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I just tried what you describe in your q and code completion continues to work fine.

Here's exactly what I did:

- Created a new multi-platform application.
- Saved the default new Form1 unit the IDE creates and the project.
- Created a new unit and cut and pasted the source of FMX.IniFile into it.
- Saved the new unit in the project's folder under the name FMX.IniFile.Pas
- Added `FMX.IniFile` to Form1's unit's Uses clause.
- Added a TButton to Form1 and did a Save All
- Created a `Button1Click' event on Form1.
- Switched from the form editor to the code editor and, in the `Button1Click` handler skeleton and started to type

  `Self.c`

and the IDE immediately offered the various properties of Form1 beginning with `c` as code-completion possibilities.

I'm using Delphi 10.2.3 on Windows 10 Pro 64-bit.

Comment: That's exactly what i did, so i still don't know what the problem is - i already tried that with two different version of Delphi, it did this thing both times. Have you imported The FMX.inifile.Android.pas and the other files from the github source?

Comment: No, because your q asks specifically about FMX.IniFile.Pas. Anyway, now you should be able to eliminate FMX.IniFile.Pas from your list of suspects.

Comment: Oh sorry, that's my mistake. In order to use the file cross-platform, i need to import the other files in the Directory as well, so the ones for android and iPhone. You're right, it was probably not the fault of the Fmx.Inifile.pas, but then i have no plan where the issue is, as the code completion just deactivates as soon as i add it

Comment: Well, just start again.  Delete all the files from GitHub, restart the IDE, new project, new project folder, etc.  Add whatever GitHub files one by one and test after each one.  Tedious I know but it's the only way to narrow down a problem like this.

Comment: Thanks, i will try this, maybe it will help to find the problem. I just looked in the other files and while opening them in Delphi, it gives a few warnings that some of the functions might be outdated - but it works properly. Might the code completion have an issue with that?

Comment: Sorry I have no idea and wouldn't want to speculate.

Comment: Hm okay, i will try to find the issue myself again, thanks anyways